# Efficient way in R to add a new column to a dataframe with huge dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dataset, data.table

I really need to speed some R code up. I have a large dataset from a particular sport. Each row in the data frame represents some type of action in the game. For each game (`game_id`) we have two teams (`team_id`) that take part in the game. `time_ref` in the data frame are the actions in chronological order for each game. `type_id` is the type of action in the game. `player_off` is set as `TRUE` or `FALSE` and is linked to `action_id=3`. `action_id=3` represents a player getting a card and `player_off` is set to `TRUE`/`FALSE` if the player was sent off when they got that card. Example data.frame:

```
> df

game_id team_id action_id   player_off  time_ref
100     10         1             NA       1000
100     10         1             NA       1001
100     10         1             NA       1002
100     11         1             NA       1003
100     11         2             NA       1004
100     11         1             NA       1005
100     10         3             1        1006
100     11         1             NA       1007
100     10         1             NA       1008
100     10         1             NA       1009
101     12         3             0        1000
101     12         1             NA       1001
101     12         1             NA       1002
101     13         2             NA       1003
101     13         3             1        1004
101     12         1             NA       1005
101     13         1             NA       1006
101     13         1             NA       1007
101     12         1             NA       1008
101     12         1             NA       1009
```

What I need is another column in the data frame that gives me `TRUE` or `FALSE` on whether both teams had an equal/unequal number of players on the field while each action (row) took place.

So `game_id=100` had an `action_id=3` & `player_off=1` for `team_id=10` at `time_ref=1006`. So we know the teams were equal with number of players on the field up to that point but unequal for the rest of the game (`time_ref>1006`). The same thing occurred in `game_id=101` also.

This an example of the data frame with an extra column I would like to have for the dataset.

```
>df
game_id team_id action_id   player_off  time_ref    is_even
100      10        1            NA        1000         1
100      10        1            NA        1001         1
100      10        1            NA        1002         1 
100      11        1            NA        1003         1
100      11        2            NA        1004         1
100      11        1            NA        1005         1
100      10        3            1         1006         1
100      11        1            NA        1007         0
100      10        1            NA        1008         0
100      10        1            NA        1009         0
101      12        3            0         1000         1
101      12        1            NA        1001         1
101      12        1            NA        1002         1
101      13        2            NA        1003         1
101      13        3            1         1004         1
101      12        1            NA        1005         0
101      13        1            NA        1006         0
101      13        1            NA        1007         0
101      12        1            NA        1008         0
101      12        1            NA        1009         0
```

So you can see that in `game_id=100` a player was sent off at `time_ref=1006` so all previous rows were marked as `is_even=1` and subsequent marked as uneven or `0`. Similar for `game_id=101` at `time_ref=1004`.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this extra column? Preferably not using for loops.

Comment: The "most efficient" way is probably to write C code for your special case; is this really what you are asking for?

Comment: I know what you mean but I'd prefer to keep it in R actually.

Comment: The comment still applies -- you're not looking for 'the most efficient', but something that's reasonably efficient for the task at hand. And the task isn't how to add a new column to a data frame, but how to transform a column by groups. I guess I'm trying to tell you to revise your title (this might help you find existing questions and answers).

Comment: True. I've removed "most" from the title.

Comment: With data.table, your example is handled by `mDT = DT[player_off == 1, .(game_id, time_ref)]; DT[, is_even := 1L][mDT, on=.(game_id, time_ref > time_ref), is_even := 0L]` but I guess your example is not general enough (eg, doesn't show what happens after both teams have a player off and are even again).

Answer (score 5):

For some vector

```
x = c(0, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)
```

write a function to standardize the data (0 or 1 player lost), calculate the cumulative number of players lost, and compare this to zero,

```
fun0 = function(x)  {
    x[is.na(x)] = 0
    cumsum(x) == 0
}
```

For several groups, use `ave()` with a grouping variable

```
x = c(x, rev(x))
grp = rep(1:2, each = length(x) / 2)
ave(x, grp, FUN = fun0)
```

For the data in the question, try

```
df$is_even = ave(df$player_off, df$game_id, FUN = fun)
```

Semantically, it seems likely that `fun0()` is more complicated than implied in this solution, specifically that if each team loses a player, they are again even, as @SunLisa says. If so, clean the data

```
df$player_off[is.na(df$player_off)] = 0
```

and change `fun0()`, e.g.,

```
fun1 <- function(x, team) {
    is_team_1 <- team == head(team, 1) # is 'team' the first team?
    x1 <- x & is_team_1                # lost player & team 1
    x2 <- x & !is_team_1               # lost player & team 2
    cumsum(x1) == cumsum(x2)           # same total number of players?
}
```

(it doesn't seem like a good idea to coerce the logical return value to an integer). This could be applied by group with

```
df$is_even = ave(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$game_id, FUN = function(i) {
    fun1(df$player_off[i], df$team_id[i])
})
```

or

```
split(df$is_even, df$game_id) <-
    Map(fun1,
        split(df$player_off, df$game_id),
        split(df$team_id, df$game_id)
    )
```

The implementation of `ave()` is useful to look at, the important line being

```
split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)
```

The right-hand side splits `x` by group `g`, then applies `FUN()` to each group. The left-hand side `split<-()` is a tricky operation, using the group indexes to update the original vector `x`.

## Comments

The original question asked for 'no for loops', but actually `lapply()` (in `ave()`) and `Map()` are exactly that; `ave()` is relatively efficient because of the split-apply-combine strategy it adopts, rather than what the OP probably implemented, which was likely to iterate through games, subset the data frame, then update the data.frame for each game. The subsetting would have duplicated subsets of the entire data set, and the update in particular would have copied at least the entire result column on each assignment; this copying would have slowed the execution down alot. It's also possible that the OP was struggling with `fun0()`; it would help to clarify the question, especially title, to identify that as the problem.

There are faster ways, especially using the data.table package, but the principle is the same -- identify a function that operates on a vector the way you'd like, and apply it by group.

An alternative, fully-vectorized, solution follows [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898494/vectorize-cumsum-by-factor-in-r/35898949#comment59461625_35898949) to  calculate a cumulative sum by group. For `fun0()`, standardize `x` to be the number of players leaving the game at a particular timepoint, without NAs

```
x[is.na(x)] = 0
```

For the equivalent of `fun()`, calculate the cumulative sum of players leaving the game, irrespective of group

```
cs = cumsum(x)
```

Correct this for the group that the cumulative sum applies to

```
in_game = cs - (grp - 1)
```

and set this to 'TRUE' when 0 players have left the game

```
is_even = (in_game == 0)
```

This relies on `grp` indexing from 1 to the number of groups; for the data here one might `grp = match(df$game_id, unique(df$game_id))`. A similar solution exists for `fun1()`.

Comment: Tried running your code and the `is_even` column seems to overshoot by 1 cell. For example, in `game_id` = 100, the answer should be 7 1s and the rest 0s, but in yours, it's 8 1s and the rest 0s.

Comment: This is a nice start but it doesn't return the correct vector. It gives the last 5 data points in is_even as 1,0,0,1,1 when they should all be false as a player was sent off at time_ref=1004.

Comment: So for `ave()` the team_id doesn't matter; don't include it as a grouping variable.

Comment: Nice, it works if you exclude `df$team_id` from `ave`. Can you explain what your code does, in particular the `fun` function that you made and the base `ave` function?

Comment: @Anonymous I updated the answer to walk through the code in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` + `tidyr` solution to the problem, with the summary of what was done:

1. Manipulate the data by converting all NAs in `player_off` to 0 for easier summing and assigning the smaller `team_num` (assuming there are only 2) to `team1` and the other to `team2`
2. "Tally" the `player_off`s using `spread` and fill the invalid combinations in the data with 0 -- for example, in `game_id` = 100, there's no `team_id` = 11 for `time_ref` = 1000
3. Take the cumulative sum of the `lag`ged `team1` and `team2` vectors (and of course fill NAs with 0)

Code below:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(game_id) %>%
  mutate(
    player_off = player_off %>% replace(list = is.na(.), values = 0),
    team_num = if_else(team_id == min(team_id), "team1", "team2")
  ) %>%
  spread(key = team_num, value = player_off, fill = 0) %>%
  arrange(game_id, time_ref) %>%
  mutate(
    team1_cum = cumsum(lag(team1, default = 0)),
    team2_cum = cumsum(lag(team2, default = 0)),
    is_even = as.integer(team1_cum == team2_cum)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-team1, -team2, -team1_cum, -team2_cum)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   game_id team_id action_id time_ref is_even
     <int>   <int>     <int>    <int>   <int>
 1     100      10         1     1000       1
 2     100      10         1     1001       1
 3     100      10         1     1002       1
 4     100      11         1     1003       1
 5     100      11         2     1004       1
 6     100      11         1     1005       1
 7     100      10         3     1006       1
 8     100      11         1     1007       0
 9     100      10         1     1008       0
10     100      10         1     1009       0
11     101      12         3     1000       1
12     101      12         1     1001       1
13     101      12         1     1002       1
14     101      13         2     1003       1
15     101      13         3     1004       1
16     101      12         1     1005       0
17     101      13         1     1006       0
18     101      13         1     1007       0
19     101      12         1     1008       0
20     101      12         1     1009       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my think:

data.table is going to work well, especially when you are working with large data sets. It's faster. We just need to group it, `cumsum` 2 team's layoff, and see if they equal.

First I have to say:

(problem solved by Martin Morgan, his updated answer no longer has this error)

I don't think @Martin Morgan 's answer is right. Let's imagine a certain case:

when team 1 had one player off, after which team 2 had another player off, then 2 teams should be even, but @Martin Morgan's output would be `FALSE`.

I'll make an example with this dataset, where `player_off` of `record 19` was modified to `1`, which means that in game `101`, after `team 13` had had `1 player off` at `1004`, `team 12` had `1 player off` at `1008`, which would make 2 teams even at `1009`.

```
> dt.1
   game_id team_id action_id player_off time_ref
1      100      10         1         NA     1000
2      100      10         1         NA     1001
3      100      10         1         NA     1002
4      100      11         1         NA     1003
5      100      11         2         NA     1004
6      100      11         1         NA     1005
7      100      10         3          1     1006
8      100      11         1         NA     1007
9      100      10         1         NA     1008
10     100      10         1         NA     1009
11     101      12         3          0     1000
12     101      12         1         NA     1001
13     101      12         1         NA     1002
14     101      13         2         NA     1003
15     101      13         3          1     1004
16     101      12         1         NA     1005
17     101      13         1         NA     1006
18     101      13         1         NA     1007
19     101      12         1          1     1008
20     101      12         1         NA     1009
```

But @Martin Morgan 's function would produce this output:

```
> dt.1$is_even = ave(df$player_off, df$game_id, FUN = fun)
> dt.1
   game_id team_id action_id player_off time_ref is_even
1      100      10         1         NA     1000       1
2      100      10         1         NA     1001       1
3      100      10         1         NA     1002       1
4      100      11         1         NA     1003       1
5      100      11         2         NA     1004       1
6      100      11         1         NA     1005       1
7      100      10         3          1     1006       1
8      100      11         1         NA     1007       0
9      100      10         1         NA     1008       0
10     100      10         1         NA     1009       0
11     101      12         3          0     1000       1
12     101      12         1         NA     1001       1
13     101      12         1         NA     1002       1
14     101      13         2         NA     1003       1
15     101      13         3          1     1004       1
16     101      12         1         NA     1005       0
17     101      13         1         NA     1006       0
18     101      13         1         NA     1007       0
19     101      12         1          1     1008       0
20     101      12         1         NA     1009       0
```

Notice how at `line 19` and `line 20`, `is.even=0`. Which is not what op wants.

My code does not process `NA`s, so I am going to transform `NA` to `0` first.

```
> dt.1<-as.data.table(dt.1)
> dt.1[is.na(dt.1)]<-0
```

My code would produce the correct output, at time `1008` and `1009`, where both `team 12` and `team 13` had 1 off, two teams are even.

```
> dt.1[,.(action_id,team2_off=(team_id==max(team_id))*player_off,team1_off=(team_id==min(team_id))*player_off,team_id,time_ref,player_off),by=game_id][order(game_id,time_ref)][,.(team_id,time_ref,action_id,player_off,even=as.numeric(cumsum(team2_off)==cumsum(team1_off))),by=game_id]
    game_id team_id time_ref action_id player_off even
 1:     100      10     1000         1          0    1
 2:     100      10     1001         1          0    1
 3:     100      10     1002         1          0    1
 4:     100      11     1003         1          0    1
 5:     100      11     1004         2          0    1
 6:     100      11     1005         1          0    1
 7:     100      10     1006         3          1    0
 8:     100      11     1007         1          0    0
 9:     100      10     1008         1          0    0
10:     100      10     1009         1          0    0
11:     101      12     1000         3          0    1
12:     101      12     1001         1          0    1
13:     101      12     1002         1          0    1
14:     101      13     1003         2          0    1
15:     101      13     1004         3          1    0
16:     101      12     1005         1          0    0
17:     101      13     1006         1          0    0
18:     101      13     1007         1          0    0
19:     101      12     1008         1          1    1
20:     101      12     1009         1          0    1
```

I understand it is a messy looking chunk of data.table code, let me explain step by step.

```
dt[, .(
  action_id,
  team2_off = (team_id == max(team_id)) * player_off,
  team1_off = (team_id == min(team_id)) * player_off,
  team_id,
  time_ref,
  player_off
), by = game_id][order(game_id, time_ref)][, .(team_id,
                                               time_ref,
                                               action_id,
                                               player_off,
                                               even = cumsum(team2_off) == cumsum(team1_off)), by = game_id]
```

first, we take data.table `dt`, group by `game_id`, and does this calculation:

```
  team2_off = (team_id == max(team_id)) * player_off,
  team1_off = (team_id == min(team_id)) * player_off
```

data.table has some problem taking 2 grouping at once (group by `game_id` and `team_id`), but it handles logical expression inside of each group well. In this way, we effectively get `team1_off` and `team2_off`, by multiplying a logical output of `team_id == max/min(team_id)` with `player_off`. When both are 1, the output would be 1, which means, 1 player was off in the selected team.

Now we have a data table of:

```
> dt.1[,.(action_id,team2_off=(team_id==max(team_id))*player_off,team1_off=(team_id==min(team_id))*player_off,team_id,time_ref,player_off),by=game_id]
    game_id action_id team2_off team1_off team_id time_ref player_off
 1:     100         1         0         0      10     1000          0
 2:     100         1         0         0      10     1001          0
 3:     100         1         0         0      10     1002          0
 4:     100         1         0         0      11     1003          0
 5:     100         2         0         0      11     1004          0
 6:     100         1         0         0      11     1005          0
 7:     100         3         0         1      10     1006          1
 8:     100         1         0         0      11     1007          0
 9:     100         1         0         0      10     1008          0
10:     100         1         0         0      10     1009          0
11:     101         3         0         0      12     1000          0
12:     101         1         0         0      12     1001          0
13:     101         1         0         0      12     1002          0
14:     101         2         0         0      13     1003          0
15:     101         3         1         0      13     1004          1
16:     101         1         0         0      12     1005          0
17:     101         1         0         0      13     1006          0
18:     101         1         0         0      13     1007          0
19:     101         1         0         1      12     1008          1
20:     101         1         0         0      12     1009          0
```

Now we no longer need to group by two groups (`team_id`, `game_id`), we can just do `cumsum` by `game_id`, and compare if `cumsum(team1_off)==cumsum(team2_off)`, also, `order` it by `game_id` and `time_ref`, so the result would have the correct order.

I understand that `NA`s may have different meanings than `0` in this scenario. If you really care that much, just create a `dummy` column of `player_off`.

```
> dt$dummy<-dt$player_off
> dt$dummy[is.na(dt$dummy)]<-0
> dt<-as.data.table(dt)
> dt[, .(
+   action_id,
+   team2_off = (team_id == max(team_id)) * dummy,
+   team1_off = (team_id == min(team_id)) * dummy,
+   team_id,
+   time_ref,
+   player_off
+ ), by = game_id][order(game_id, time_ref)][, .(team_id,
+                                                time_ref,
+                                                action_id,
+                                                player_off,
+                                                even = as.numeric(cumsum(team2_off) == cumsum(team1_off))), by = game_id]
    game_id team_id time_ref action_id player_off even
 1:     100      10     1000         1         NA    1
 2:     100      10     1001         1         NA    1
 3:     100      10     1002         1         NA    1
 4:     100      11     1003         1         NA    1
 5:     100      11     1004         2         NA    1
 6:     100      11     1005         1         NA    1
 7:     100      10     1006         3          1    0
 8:     100      11     1007         1         NA    0
 9:     100      10     1008         1         NA    0
10:     100      10     1009         1         NA    0
11:     101      12     1000         3          0    1
12:     101      12     1001         1         NA    1
13:     101      12     1002         1         NA    1
14:     101      13     1003         2         NA    1
15:     101      13     1004         3          1    0
16:     101      12     1005         1         NA    0
17:     101      13     1006         1         NA    0
18:     101      13     1007         1         NA    0
19:     101      12     1008         1         NA    0
20:     101      12     1009         1         NA    0
```

I really think you question is very interesting, and I was dedicated to solve this using data.table. It took me few hours and I almost gave up on data.table, thinking that data.table just can't process two grouping at a time. I eventually solved it with a logical multiplication.

Great fun I had

```
  team1_off = (team_id == min(team_id)) * dummy
  team2_off = (team_id == max(team_id)) * dummy
```

Comment: I agree that my answer doesn't handle both teams losing players; the original question isn't clear, though semantically `is_even` implies your interpretation. I updated my response to reflect the different interpretation.

Comment: @Martin Morgan, I'm really impressed by your function solution. As you said in your post, the ultimate idea is get a function which can produce the right result. Although this question is kinda tricky, your solution is highly inspiring! Thanks for your inspiration. It takes me some time to understand your function.